# How to pass a variable to find's name option?

Tags: bash, shell

dupes.txt contains a list of file strings without their extensions (found by comparing base names without extensions). I can get this to echo the lines:

```
files=`cat dupes.txt`; for f in "$files"; do echo "$f"; done
```

I'm trying to then pass "$f" to the find command's name option

```
files=`cat dupes.txt`; for f in "$files"; do find . -type f -name "$f"; done
```

But nothing is returned. Suggestions most welcome. In other words, I want to find all files matching the pattern in the text file.

I've tried

```
find . -type f | fgrep -f dupes.txt
```

but this doesn't restrict find's output to those files matching the file strings in dupes.txt.

I'm working in the bash shell on OS X, by the way.

Answer (score 4):

This is wrong:

```
files=`cat dupes.txt`; for f in "$files"; do echo "$f"; done
```

Because you're quoting `"$files"`, the shell has no opportunity to split the variable on whitespace. Thus, inside the loop `"$f"` will contain the entire contents of the file.

To iterate over the contents of a file, choose one of

```
while IFS= read -r f; do ...; done < dupes.txt
# or
mapfile -t files < dupes.txt; for f in "${files[@]}"; do ...; done
```

---

Here's a complicated way to create the pattern, but you only have to call `find` once, and that's a big win:

```
find_args=()
while IFS= read -r file; do
    find_args+=( -o -name "${file}*" )
done < dupes.txt
find . -type f \( "${find_args[@]:1}" \)
```

Comment: Thanks, Glenn. I will give this a try. I do not want to call find more than once, for sure. (I was trying a 'while read line' script and noticed that).

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
files=$(cat dupes.txt)
for f in $files; do find . -type f -name "${f}*"; done
```

Comment: In other words, you need to specify a wildcard in the 
 -name parameter.

Comment: And not quoting $files to take advantage of word splitting

Comment: And not quoting `$files` will make the code subject to pathname expansions.

Comment: And this fails for file names containing whitespace.

Comment: Thanks; I was not aware of the    "${f}*" syntax

Answer (score 0):

```
while read i; do
    find -type f -name "${i}*"
done < dupes.txt
```

Comment: The parentheses are unnecessary; the `while` loop itself can take the input redirection.

Comment: Removed, 10x @chepner